# Split shapefile polygon according to the NAME_1 in R

Tags: r, polygon, subset, shapefile

If a polygon can not be sub-setted by its attributes, how can I split it according to the attributes in force?

```
require(raster)
chnshp<-getData('GADM', country="China", level=1)
chnshp  #     nfeatures   : 32 
row.names(chnshp) #  
chnshp$NAME_1  #   
chnshp$NAME_1=='Hainan' # Only one row is True
row.names(chnshp[chnshp$NAME_1=='Hainan'])  #   32 rows
chnshp[chnshp$NAME_1=='Hainan']    #     nfeatures   : 32 
plot(chnshp[chnshp$NAME_1=='Hainan'])  #   the entire China plot?
```

Question:

How to split it according to the column `NAME_1`?

Make sure that `chnshp[chnshp$NAME_1=='Hainan']` return the Hainan area.

Comment: This must be dependent on some unnamed package or packages.

Comment: getData is a method of the raster package  @DWin . Sorry for missing the require declaration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "[" extraction function rather than  "[[".

```
plot(chnshp[chnshp$NAME_1=='Hainan', ])
```

It makes more sense to send a logical vector of length 32 to "[" than to "[[" which is expecting a length one argument. (And it's probably better not to refer to these as 'attributes', since that is a term with particular meaning in R.

[image]